# gomplate: executing "<arg>" at <.Values.tpl.organization>: map has no entry for key "Values"

Tags: go, gomplate

Here is my yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: myapi.com/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.tpl.organization }}-template-mkytemplatetemplate
spec:
  # Add fields here
  organization: {{ .Values.tpl.organization }}
  purpose: {{ .Values.tpl.purpose }}
  version: {{ .Chart.appVersion }}
  location: {{.Values.location}}/template.tgz
  name: mkytemplatetemplate
  namePattern: ^[a-z0-9\-]{3,25}$
  description: "# Please do not use the template\ntest modify run.sh"
  author: string
```

I use gomplate to replace all {{xxx}} to corresponding values in Chart.yaml or Values.yaml. Here is my code

```golang
func main() {
    log.Println("hello")
    //BasicTemplate()
    Gomplate()
}

func Gomplate() {
    workspace := "/Users/i517131/code/mkytemplatetemplate/.ci/chart"
    inBs, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(path.Join(workspace, "templates/template.yaml"))
    in := string(inBs)
    cfg := &gomplate.Config{
        Input: in,
        OutputFiles: []string{path.Join(workspace, "result.yaml")},
        DataSources: []string{
            fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", "Chart", path.Join(workspace, "Chart.yaml")),
            fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", "Values", path.Join(workspace, "values.yaml")),
        },
    }
    err := gomplate.RunTemplates(cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

but I receive an error like this `panic: template: <arg>:4:18: executing "<arg>" at <.Values.tpl.organization>: map has no entry for key "Values"`. at `err := gomplate.RunTemplates(cfg)`

At first, when I run cmd `gomplate -f .ci/chart/templates/template.yaml -d Chart=.ci/chart/Chart.yaml -d Values=.ci/chart/values.yaml -o result.yaml`, I receive the save error.
I searched the internet and in [github](https://github.com/hairyhenderson/gomplate/issues/555), the author suggest us use `-c` instead of `-d`

But the gomplate in go can only use gomplate.Config to run templates and do not support `-c`. What can I do?

result generated by -c cmd

```yaml
apiVersion: myapi.com/v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: mky-template-mkytemplatetemplate
spec:
  # Add fields here
  organization: mky
  purpose: prod
  version: 1.0.0
  location: _/template.tgz
  name: mkytemplatetemplate
  namePattern: ^[a-z0-9\-]{3,25}$
  description: "# Please do not use the template\ntest modify run.sh"
  author: string
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Contexts` not `DataSource`

```
cfg := &gomplate.Config{
        Input: in,
        OutputFiles: []string{path.Join(workspace, "result.yaml")},
        Contexts: []string{
            fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", "Chart", path.Join(workspace, "Chart.yaml")),
            fmt.Sprintf("%s=%s", "Values", path.Join(workspace, "values.yaml")),
        },
    }
```